# Getting a public static void class to read an array from another class

Tags: java

Here is said class

```
public static void showCodes(){
            System.out.print("  Select from");
            System.out.print("  =>  ");
            for (String show : productDB.inventory)
            { System.out.print(show.toUpperCase() + " ");}
            System.out.print("  <=");
     }
```

Here is the other class (that has the array)

```
public class ProductDB
{
public String[] inventory = {"java", "jsps", "mcb2", "txtp", "calc", "topg", "bigl", "sgtp"};
**insert rest of class code**
}
```

this is my main

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
System.out.println("  Product Selection\n");
showCodes();
  ...
```

I understand that I need to define my variable, but I'm fairly new to Java.
In the first block code, on line 4, I get a "cannot find symbol" error.

Comment: In what class is `showCodes` defined? Perhaps you should provide a full example which demonstrates you problem

Comment: Did you do `ProductDB productDB = new ProductDB();`?

Comment: You can write your method like this: `public static void showCodes(ProductDB productDB){`; then in your `main` call it with `showCodes(new ProductDB())`.

Comment: I did do     ProductDB productDB = new ProductDB(); I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Holy moly, QBrute, you are a legend!

Answer (score -1):

Change `for` loop in the method `showCodes` to:

```
for (String show : ProductDB.inventory)
```

and add `static` to the array definiation in the class, as following:

```
public static String[] inventory = {"java", "jsps", "mcb2", "txtp", "calc", "topg", "bigl", "sgtp"};
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but QBrute in the comments helped me earlier. I really appreciate you (and everyone else) taking their time for such a dumb little question.

Comment: That changes the semantics of the program. What if the `inventory` variable is supposed to be an instance variable?  The question is not yet answerable as it is unclear what is needed.

Comment: @BodhiConfer-wood , however, this is another solution. BTW, you welcome!

Comment: @JimGarrison , this suggestion could solve the current situation. if you want to speak about the semantic of OOP, the showCodes method shouldn't be static at all.

Comment: By the way, I am working with copyrighted code (code from a book) so posting all of the code online would be illegal. Would I get caught, nah, but I would feel personal guilt.